# How to register a work created through coding on Opensea

Tags: nft

The work I created is made with code, and Opensea can only upload things like images and videos. Can't I upload generative art made with code?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? What kind of work are you talking about? Opensea work with NFTs which are also code behind the scenes. Know more about NFTs here - https://www.zaryabs.com/ethereum-token-standards-part-erc721/

Comment: We created generative art through computer processing. Because it was processed through processing, it was created as a code, and I would like to upload the code through upload.

Maybe I don't understand because I'm not an expert.

If it is not an image or video source, can I upload it through the API?

Answer (score 1):

Opensea allows you to upload png, jpegs, gifs etc ie media files.
[image]

As you want to upload code, which must be a different file, you can try one workaround. You upload this code somehwere(preferably decentralized storage) & As you will be minting this code on Opensea, you paste the link of already uploaded code in description, or even better.. create your own metadata field. Opensea will give you option for that,.